# backbone.js automatic PUT after POST

Tags: backbone.js, sinatra

Our server saves the model, and returns the JSON as specified in the doc. The problem is, backbone.js issues PUT as soon as it receives response. Can it be because the model is sent without _id property, and the server appends that to a model?

Comment: Any code for us to look at?

Comment: There is too much and it's proprietary. And taking out some things might affect this behaviour. I was hoping that someone encountered this in their environment (a common reason, like adding id field on the server) and could share their solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that Backbone automatically issues a PUT based on the response to a previous request, you are confused. Backbone does no such thing. If you a see a PUT going over the wire, something in your code base (an event binding or otherwise) is calling either `save` on a model or a manual `sync`.

Otherwise, you'll need to post code in order for us to help you debug, but I can assure you backbone itself will not ever issue a network request that is not triggered by external code through one of a very small set of methods such as `fetch`, `save`, or `sync`.

As to IDs on the server, that should be perfectly fine. In fact, if backbone were to get confused and think that an existing model was a new model, it would issue a POST instead of a PUT, which is not what you are seeing.